# Convergence in $\ell_p$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Why does the convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^{p_0}$, for some $p_0\geq1$ and fixed $x_i$'s, imply the convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^{p}$ for $p>p_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't too tough. You should assume each $x_i \ge 0$ so that everything is real.

The fact that $\sum x_i^{p_0}$ converges implies $x_i^{p_0} \to 0$ so that $M = \sup x_i < \infty$.

If $p > p_0$ then 
$$\sum x_i^p = \sum x_i^{p - p_0} x_i^{p_0} \le M^{p - p_0} \sum x_i^{p_0} < \infty.$$

---

It is instructive to take things one step further. Clearly $M^{p_0} \le \sum x_i^{p_0}$ so that
$$M^{p - p_0} = M^{p_0(p/p_0 - 1)} \le \left( \sum x_i^{p_0} \right)^{p/p_0 - 1}.$$ In light of the inequality just established it follows that
$$\sum x_i^p \le \left( \sum x_i^{p_0} \right)^{p/p_0 - 1} \sum x_i^{p_0} = \left( \sum x_i^{p_0} \right)^{p/p_0 }.$$
That is,
$$\left( \sum x_i^p \right)^{1/p} \le \left( \sum x_i^{p_0} \right)^{1/p_0}.$$